# How to give discord roles with a bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im using the discord.py library and using replit for the bot, but my code doesnt work.

my code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.utils import get
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))




@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == ";":
        member = message.author
        role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Recruiter")
        await member.add_roles(role)




client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: If you don't want to code a bot and do it the simple way, `Reaction Roles` bot will do the work for you.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error/tracebacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using client object and it is not a bot.

This is the way to create a proper bot (not client):

```py
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

You can't code reactions roles without reading the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It involves lots of stuff.
If you want to code it yourself, the only way is to learn and do.

Comment: Thanks but I dont understand the docs, I read the part about roles

Comment: @Martin , I'm sorry you can't do anything without reading the docs, there are tutorials available but most of them might be outdated and may not work properly. Docs are the only way. If you want examples you can find it on multiple repositories, including 
 dpy's [repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/v1.7.3/examples)

Answer (score 0):

A detailed way to do so in Python.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, role_name: str):
    """
    A command that adds a role to a member
    """
    # Get the role object from the server's roles list
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role_name)
    
    # Check if the role exists
    if role is None:
        await ctx.send(f"Role '{role_name}' not found")
        return
    
    # Add the role to the member
    try:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"Added role '{role_name}' to {member.mention}")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("I don't have permission to add roles")

bot.run("your_bot_token")
```